CommonsRequestLoggingFilter not logging when override
The following code does not log when I add in the override methods. If I replace the code without the override the log works fine.
Has seen in multiple conversations, I added the following properties:
logging.level.com.mypackage.myproject.RequestLoggingConfiguration=TRACE(or DEBUG) logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=TRACE
Using Spring Boot 3.2.3
And spring-boot-log4j2 dependency.
I'm just tryna remove the after log from the Logger, but the logger doesn't seems to work anymore...
Here is the code :
    @Bean 
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter() { 
            @Override 
            protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) { 
                 
            }
    };

    filter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    filter.setIncludeHeaders(true);
    filter.setIncludePayload(true);
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    filter.setBeforeMessagePrefix("Request started => ");
    filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("Request ended => ");
    
    
    return filter;

}

In contrast, the following code successfully logs the output:
@Bean 
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    filter.setIncludePayload(true); filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
    filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
    filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA: ");
    return filter;
}

log4j2.xml
<logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>


Same observation with my code.

I think that the problem lies in the fact that Spring expects to use the logger that has exactly the same class name as stated in the configuration. When you create an anonymous class inline, you actually create a class that has slightly different class name. Whatever the class name of the anonymous class, it's certainly different from the class name in the configuration. But if you create a real class that extends the CommonsRequestLoggingFilter and use that real class name in the configuration, everything works as expected :)
So, this will work (note that my root package is rs.in.luka.*, I have checked the solution on my own code):
MovieRequestLoggingFilter.java
package rs.in.luka.filters;

import org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class MovieRequestLoggingFilter extends CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {
  @SuppressWarnings("null")
  @Override
  protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
  }
}

WebConfig.java
package rs.in.luka;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import rs.in.luka.filters.MovieRequestLoggingFilter;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
  @Bean
  public MovieRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
      MovieRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new MovieRequestLoggingFilter();
      loggingFilter.setBeforeMessagePrefix("REQUEST [");
      loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
      loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
      loggingFilter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
      loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
      loggingFilter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
      return loggingFilter;
  }
}

In your application.properties file just add the following line:
logging.level.rs.in.luka.filters.MovieRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG

After that you will see only BEFORE log lines.

This is to supplement the reason for such behavior, refer to Saša's answer for how to fix the issue.
This is because of using anonymous Class for extension
In CommonsRequestLoggingFilter
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldLog(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return logger.isDebugEnabled();
    }

and the logger is coming from base class, GenericFilterBean
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

getClass() here will be the anonymous class, instead of org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter, that's why shouldLog return false.
To verify this, we can try something like
    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter() {
            {
                System.out.println("class here is " + getClass());
            }
            @Override
            protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {

            }
        };
   ...

And it will print something like(my logFilter is inside org.example.Configuration)

class here is class org.example.Configuration$1

